# Возврат списка строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, return

нужно написать функцию, которая принимает список строк и возвращает каждую строку с правильным номером.
При

```
number([ ])  => [ ]
number(["a", "b", "c"])  => ["1: a", "2: b", "3: c"]
```

в моем коде не происходит вывода всех значений, а только первого

```
def number(lines):
    if lines == []:
        return []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        return f'{i+1}: {lines[i]}'
```

Comment: Потому что return завершает выполнение функции. В вашем случае сразу же после первого элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь можно использовать списковое сокращение и `enumerate`:

```
def number(lines):
    return [f"{i}: {x}" for i,x in enumerate(lines, 1)]

print(number([]))
print(number(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Вывод:

```
[]
['1: a', '2: b', '3: c']
```

Comment: `enumerate(n, 1)` что бы прям как в вопросе)

Comment: @5c0rp Да, я уже заметил и поправил )

Comment: return [f"{i+1}: {x}" for i,x in enumerate(lines)]

Comment: @Dasler Так можно, но перебирать сразу правильные итерируемые значения, а не менять их представление при печати - лучше, так код понятнее и меньше ошибок может быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf Исправил, получается функцией перебирается нумерация {i} из enumerate начиная с 1, а {x} это значения списка lines.  Каким образом функция возвращает пустой список [  ], остался только этот момент неясен...

Comment: @Dasler Ну это же `списковое` включение, оно всегда выдаёт список )  В случае, когда нечего перебирать - оно выдаёт пустой список